How do I remove this shower head to paint behind it?
I need to remove this shower head to prep the ceiling for painting:

I'm going to scrape off as much of the paint as possible, mist coat and then paint with acrylic durable matt.
I can't see any screws anywhere around the head and these are the best photos I can get of the fitting:


It doesn't seem to want to rotate off either.
Recommendations for primer also welcome.

Is there any visible hex key/allen wrench hole? If not, chances are that it just twists off. (That said, if it was my house, I’d leave it in place and just mask it with tape.)

You seem to have a dampness problem.  Paint peelling, mold growing on the ceiling and shower head.  Before spending money on paint you should fix the problem.  Perhaps the best way is to remove this section of ceiling and install an extractor fan before replacing it.  The shower head probably unscrews from a threaded pipe connector but if you demolish the ceiling around it, you can see for sure.

I agree with Jay613, but need to add that the shower head needs to be lower( farther down from the ceiling)  at least 3 inches.  Adding a fan is prefered, but it must be on a GFIC circuit .

@jay613 the problem has been solved hence redecorating now. And that's not mould on the shower head, it's green scrubbing pad residue.

@AloysiusDefenestrate I've tried unscrewing it without success

Is there any way to tilt it gently and get your phone to show you if there’s any hex fittings to undo?

@AloysiusDefenestrate I've edited the question to include the best photos I can take

Unfortunately, I’m not seeing anything obvious. Either work around it or commit to the possibility of breaking it while removing.

Do you have access above the ceiling?

@Huesmann technically yes but not without a lot of effort and trouble
